# math equations for a triangular wave

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math

I have been unsuccessfully trying to plot functions which look even remotely similar to the image below in numpy, python, matplotlib. Is there any `f(x)= ....` for this image or similar plots?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the fractional part of x creates a saw-tooth-like curve. Then subtracting half of it and taking the absolute value makes the saw tooth go both ways,

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.where((x > 2.75) & (x < 7.75), np.abs(x - np.floor(x) - 0.5) + 0.75, 1)

plt.plot(x, y, color='navy')
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: For x-values between 0 and 1, an example could be:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
y = np.where((x > 0.275) & (x < 0.775), np.abs(x*10 - np.floor(x*10) - 0.5) + 0.75, 1)

plt.plot(x, y, color='navy')
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.xlim(0, 1)
```

Comment: Hi! I have been trying to see if I can get the range of x from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you suggest me some resources in general to learn more about numpy and matplotlib? You seem to be getting stuff so easily :p

Comment: The official [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html) and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/index.html) tutorials are probably a good place to start. As well as searching stackoverflow for code examples similar to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y = np.arccos(np.cos(x))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]